# GridWalk sampler with pymc3

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

I am trying to build a GridWalk sampler (actually PolicyWalk as in [BIRL by Ramachandran et. al.](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aaai.org%2FPapers%2FIJCAI%2F2007%2FIJCAI07-416.pdf&ei=cKoQVcqdD9bdauqMgagG&usg=AFQjCNHR9PxOOkAC4knV7FNMIAiicekv1A&sig2=8gjx8_vcNvDuTxQvNuqKHw&bvm=bv.89184060,d.d2s).

**Edit**

More info: The distribution I am interested in is the reward posterior given by, 
$$ P(R|D) = \frac{1}{Z} P(D|R) P(R)$$ where $R$ is the reward which I want to sample, $D$ is observed data(demonstrations). The likelihood $P(D|R)$ is easily computed via standard RL schemes and so is the prior $P(R)$.

PolicyWalk samples $R$ by 'walking over' a grid defined by some fixed step size $\delta$, i.e. the chain is generated on $\mathbb{R}^{|S|} / \delta$.

The algorithm is based on GridWalk (see.[Vempala](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cc.gatech.edu%2F~vempala%2Fpapers%2Fsurvey.pdf&ei=Ha0QVb6zHc7haIGagagE&usg=AFQjCNHJ_8qw05ViI4ISWk-Pn24v--wBiw&sig2=rL7SUrsR-UJdOgRlKEHgVg&bvm=bv.89184060,d.d2s)).

I understand that I have to make a custom density distribution to represent my reward posterior and then a custom step method. I have made a custom grid walk proposal as follows;

```
class Proposal(object):
""" Proposal for MCMC sampling """
def __init__(self, dim):
    self.dim = dim


class GridWalkProposal(Proposal):
    """ GridWalk MCMC proposal """
    def __init__(self, dim, delta, bounded=True):
        super(GridWalkProposal, self).__init__(dim)
        self.delta = delta
        self.bounded = bounded

    def __call__(self, loc):
        new_loc = np.array(loc)
        d = choice([-self.delta, 0, self.delta])
        i = randint(self.dim)
        if self.bounded:
            if -1 <= new_loc[i]+d <= 1:
                new_loc[i] += d
            return new_loc

        new_loc[i] += d
    return new_loc
```

Now am trying to make a custom step method with something like this;

```
class PolicyWalk(object):
    def __init__(self, reward, demos, proposal_dist=GridWalkProposal):
        self.reward = reward
        self.proposal_dist = proposal_dist(S)

    def step(self, ...):
        # This is where I am stuck with how to add a likelihood that
        # is a function of `demos`and the new sample
```

**Edit**

I need help with writing the code for the step method and incorporating the likelihood while doing that.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. This seems rather open-ended & possibly not really statistical / about ML. Can you clarify your question & its statistical aspect?

Comment: I added some more info on the model and esp the posterior distribution. Let me know if this is still insufficient.

Comment: Thank you. I think that is helpful. It still seems that your explicit question amounts to "any ideas appreciated", though. Can you make your question more explicit & concrete? Eg something w/ a question mark? Are you asking for help w/ the posterior or w/ the code?

Comment: Thanks, just clarified again that it is the code I need a hand on

Comment: I appreciate your continued efforts. Unfortunately, I know neither MCMC nor Python well enough to be able to tell if the code help you need is about how Python code works (which would be off-topic here), or about how the likelihood works & how to represent that in your code (which would be on-topic). We'll see what others think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally get the likelihood for the model from `model.logp` after you have build your model elsewhere. Have you read [tutorial section on model building](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/getting_started/#a-motivating-example-linear-regression)?

Then, you can pass in the model and access and store `model.logp` or `model.fastlogp` (which takes a single array instead of a dict), which are the functions that compute the likelihood of your model. Then you can use them in your step method. You may find it useful to look at the definition of the [Metropolis sampler](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/aa70f4a3ab9f79d1edb88f6d3037b21742202e36/pymc3/step_methods/metropolis.py). Perhaps you can modify Metropolis to fit your project.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes indeed your advice helped, I extended the MH, now cleaning it up so I put it online.